# How to determine orientation of home screen

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-appwidget, android-orientation, homescreen

Is there a way to determine programmatically the orientation of the home screen?  I've toyed with the following:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

and

```
Resources r = context.getResources();
int orientation = r.getConfiguration().orientation;
```

But neither seems particularly suitable because, as I understand it, the home screen may well be locked in a particular orientation, even if the screen orientation is changing.  Most notably, phone-like devices seem to be locked in portrait orientation, whereas tablet screens seem to have homescreens that rotate, though which perhaps can be locked too.

Basically I need the information in order to update a home screen widget correctly (to determine its width and height using e.g. `OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH` and `OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT` if in portrait).  But if the screen happens to be in landscape while the widget is updating in the background, it is getting width and height the wrong way around because the home screen will actually be in portrait.

Any way to get the home screen orientation reliably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to determine programmatically the orientation of the home screen?

No. The author of the home screen can do whatever the author wants. For all you know, things are displayed on a diagonal. And, since there are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of home screen implementations, the behavior on any given device will be indeterminate.

Comment: Doesn't seem particularly satisfactory.  Any idea as to how to determine a widget's wxh for a device that may have the homescreen in either orientation?  I've got it working OK assuming the homescreen is portrait, but struggling when the homescreen could be landscape.  There must *surely* be a way of working out the width and height of a widget??

Comment: @drmrbrewer: Ask the user whether their home screen is locked to portrait, locked to landscape, or freely rotates. Or, design your app widget UI such that the home screen orientation does not matter. You already have to have flexibility for dealing with a width or height within a range -- you could extend it to support the overall range (i.e., the smaller of the two minimums and the larger of the two maximums).

Comment: funny, I had just come to the same conclusion, absent any automatic way of determining this info... was about to implement a user option so that they can specify.  Shame that this information isn't available programatically though.  Thanks.